# D3 Color Legend: Trouble Making a Legend with uneven decimal value Widths but equal Height

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, heatmap

EXCUSES: Hi, so I'm just sick of this project and am tired of researching and reading. I'm learning HTML, CSS, and D3.js by myself and am trying to make a Heat Map. Some how making the actual map was easy as cake but making this color legend has been the absolute death of me and just want the answer at this point.

I'm trying to make a legend from an array of array's where the indexed arrays 1st value is equal to a temperature/tick on the axis. The 2nd value is the the color I want to fill the rectangle with; which is comprised of the current and next index. So this is my array(I assume in JS it's an array of arrays but at this point I don't even know anymore)

`const xValues = [ [2.8, "rgb(69, 117, 180)"], [3.9, "rgb(116, 173, 209)"], [5.0, "rgb(171, 217, 233)"], [6.1, "rgb(224, 243, 248)"], [7.2, "rgb(255, 255, 191)"], [8.3, "rgb(254, 224, 144)"], [9.5, "rgb(253, 174, 97)"], [10.6, "rgb(244, 109, 67)"], [11.7, "rgb(215, 48, 39)"], [12.8, ""] ];`.

So these are some of the main ideas that I assume are leading to my errors.

1. Obviously the axis is made up of decimal values which I feel is a major/main reason why I haven't seen a rectangle but I assume this might be due to Javascript decimal arithmetic or maybe something about the d3 'rect' object doesn't like that all my widths are uneven.
2. On top of that idea another reason could be that, I just don't know 100% how the scaleLinear() method works or how/when to apply it! I've tried using it in every variation with the (x, y) points and width & height attributes.
3. I've noticed when trying to access these values that they are returned as strings so rather than use scaleLinear(), I've also tried to just hard code it by returning the desired values then parseFloat() -> .round() -> Number() which also lead me to 0 results. I did however manage to return all the values in the way I wanted so am extremely confused why nothing appeared with that idea.
4. The last index in my array. I was thinking I could just stop incrementing on the last index but ran into many problems attempting to do this.
5. I decided to arrange my data in the silliest way possible and no man/machine should ever have to work with data like this.

The end goal is a recreation of this [website](https://heat-map.freecodecamp.rocks/). This legend here, I believe has equidistant ticks on the axis which makes placing the rectangles easy while mine are spaced by the actual values and then scaled for the svg.

Like I said I'm still learning and this is my 1st project incorporating Javascript into HTML & CSS so there's probably an uncountable number of mistakes. I'm aware that there probably shouldn't be 2 scripts and functions should probably be utilized but I like doing things the hard way... hence how I ended up in this position.

A detailed explanation would be amazing and very appreciated! If you think I have big fundamental mistakes, it would be awesome if you could specifically explain what I was doing incorrectly and why. If it's a tiny mistake then you could just call me a silly goose.

Here is the HTML code for my map and legend; the legend part can be found towards the bottom.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate-Heat Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Heat Map</title>
    
    
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/global-temperature.json';
        
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url);   //Synchronous is default value
        xhr.send();
        xhr.onload = function() {
          const stringOfJSON = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          let html = "";
          
          let baseTemp = stringOfJSON.baseTemperature;
          const monthlyVariance = stringOfJSON.monthlyVariance;
          
          const maxYrForXaxis = d3.max(monthlyVariance, (monthVarObj) => monthVarObj.year);
          const minYrForXaxis = d3.min(monthlyVariance, (monthVarObj) => monthVarObj.year);
          const XaxisLength = maxYrForXaxis - minYrForXaxis;
          
          const width = 1600;
          const height = 550;
          const padding = 80;
          const numOfMonths = 12;
          const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
          let degreesCelcius = String.fromCodePoint(8451);
          
          const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                           .domain([minYrForXaxis, maxYrForXaxis+1])
                           .range([padding, width - padding]);
          
          const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                           .domain([.5, numOfMonths+.5])
                           .range([height - padding, padding]);
          
          const svg = d3.select("#svgMap")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", width)
                        .attr("height", height);
          
          const g = svg.append("g")
                       .attr("transform", "translate(0, 0)");
          
          const rects = g.selectAll("rect")
                           .data(monthlyVariance)
                           .enter()
                           .append("rect")
             
            rects.attr("x", (d) => xScale(d.year)).attr("y", (d) => yScale(d.month+.5))
                 .attr("width", (d) => (width/XaxisLength)).attr("height", ((height - padding * 2)/numOfMonths))
                 .attr("fill", (d) => {
                                   const tempVar = (Math.round((baseTemp + (d.variance))*10) / 10);
              
                                   if(.8 <= tempVar && tempVar < 3.9)
                                        return "rgb(69, 117, 180)";
                                   if(3.9 <= tempVar && tempVar < 5.0)
                                        return "rgb(116, 173, 209)";
                                   if(5.0 <= tempVar && tempVar < 6.1)
                                        return "rgb(171, 217, 233)";
                                   if(6.1 <= tempVar && tempVar < 7.2)
                                        return "rgb(224, 243, 248)";
                                   if(7.2 <= tempVar && tempVar < 8.3)
                                        return "rgb(255, 255, 191)";
                                   if(8.3 <= tempVar && tempVar < 9.5)
                                        return "rgb(254, 224, 144)";
                                   if(9.5 <= tempVar && tempVar < 10.6)
                                        return "rgb(253, 174, 97)";
                                   if(10.6 <= tempVar && tempVar < 11.7)
                                        return "rgb(244, 109, 67)";
                                   if(11.7 <= tempVar && tempVar <= 32.8)
                                        return "rgb(215, 48, 39)";
                                   })
                 .attr("class", "tooltip")
                 .append("title")
                 .text((d) => ( d.year + " - " + months[d.month-1] + "\n" + (Math.round((baseTemp + (d.variance))*10) / 10) + degreesCelcius + "\n" + (Math.round(d.variance*10)/10) + degreesCelcius ) );
                                                 
          const celsius = d3.select("#description")
                            .append("tspan")
                            .text(baseTemp + degreesCelcius);
          
          const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).scale(xScale).ticks(XaxisLength/10).tickFormat(i => i);
          const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).scale(yScale).tickFormat(i => months[i-1]);
          
          const xLabel = svg.append("text")
                            .attr("x", width/2)
                            .attr("y", height-padding/2)
                            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                            .text("Years");
          
          const yLabel = svg.append("text")
                            .attr("x", -height/2)
                            .attr("y", padding/6)
                            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                            .text("Month");
          
          svg.append("g")
             .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (height - padding) + ")")
             .call(xAxis);
          
          svg.append("g")                       
             .attr("transform", "translate(" + (padding) + ", 0)")
             .call(yAxis);
          
          document.getElementsByClassName('theMap').innerHTML;
        };
      });
  </script>
    
    
    <!--                 COLOR LEGEND                  -->
    
    
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const width = 600;    
        const height = 100;
        const padding = 20;
        const colorHeight = 20;
        const xValues = [ [2.8, "rgb(69, 117, 180)"], [3.9, "rgb(116, 173, 209)"], [5.0, "rgb(171, 217, 233)"], [6.1, "rgb(224, 243, 248)"],
                          [7.2, "rgb(255, 255, 191)"], [8.3, "rgb(254, 224, 144)"], [9.5, "rgb(253, 174, 97)"], [10.6, "rgb(244, 109, 67)"],
                          [11.7, "rgb(215, 48, 39)"], [12.8, ""] ];
        
        const xMin = d3.min(xValues, (d) => d[0]);
        const xMax = d3.max(xValues, (d) => d[0]);
        
        const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                         .domain([xMin, xMax])
                         .range([padding, width - padding]);
        
        
        const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                         .domain([0, 5])
                         .range([height - padding, padding]);
        
        const svg = d3.select("#legend")
                      .append("svg")
                      .attr("width", width)
                      .attr("height", height);
        
        const g = svg.append("g")
                     .attr("transform", "translate(0, 0)");
        
        const rects = g.selectAll("rect")
                      .data(xValues)
                      .enter()
                      .append("rect")

             rects.attr("x", (d) => xScale(d[0]) ).attr("y", colorHeight)
             .attr("width", (d, i) =>   (xScale(xValues[i+1][0]) - xScale(d[0]))   ).attr("height", colorHeight)
             .attr("fill", (d) => d[1]);
                                                            
        const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
                        .tickValues(xValues.map(d => d[0]))
                        .tickFormat(d3.format(".1f"));
        
        svg.append("g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (height - padding) + ")")
           .call(xAxis);
      });
    </script>
    
    
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <header>
      <h1 id="title">Monthly Global Land-Surface Temperature</h1>
      <h2 id="description">1753-2015: Base Temperature </h2>
    </header>
    <div id="MapStuff">
      <div id="svgMap" class="theMap"></div>
      <legend id="legend"></legend>
    </div>   
    
  </body>
</html>
```

I read somewhere about an alteranate approach, to a similar problem like mine, that stemmed from the callbacks in the .attr() method returning numbers as strings due to the .data() method. This was my attempt at re-creating it by using the forEach().

```
...
const svg = d3.select("#legend")
              .append("svg")
              .attr("width", width)
              .attr("height", height);

svg.selectAll('rect')
           .data(xValues)
           .enter()
           .append('g')
           .each( (d, i) => {
             d3.select(this).selectAll("rect")
                      .data(d.xValues)
                      .enter()
                      .append("rect")
                      .attr("x", (d) => xScale(d[0]) ).attr("y", colorHeight)
                      .attr("width", (d, i) =>   (xScale(xValues[i+1][0]) - xScale(d[0]))   ).attr("height", colorHeight)
                      .attr("fill", (d) => d[1]);
           });
...
```

The final thing I tried was the hard coding which I assumed would work but didn't :(

```
const svg = d3.select("#legend")
                      .append("svg")
                      .attr("width", width)
                      .attr("height", height);

const g = svg.append("g")
                     .attr("transform", "translate(0, 0)");
        
const rects = g.selectAll("rect")
               .data(xValues.length - 1)
               .enter()
               .append("rect")
               
rects.attr("x", (d) => xScale(d[0]) ).attr("y", colorHeight)
     .attr("width", (d, i) =>   xScale(  Number((Math.round(parseFloat(xValues[(i+1)] + 'e' + 1)) - Math.round(parseFloat(d[0] + 'e' + 1))) + 'e-' + 1)   )  )
     .attr("fill", (d) => d[1]);
```

P.S. To be the best person ever the final thing I wanted to do was center the 2nd and 3rd line in my tooltip so if you know how that be incredible! Thanks for your help

```
.attr("class", "tooltip")
.append("title")
.text((d) => ( d.year + " - " + months[d.month-1] + "\n" + (Math.round((baseTemp + (d.variance))*10) / 10) + degreesCelcius + "\n" + (Math.round(d.variance*10)/10) + degreesCelcius ) );
```